# Stuck. Index out of bounds. Can't figure out why

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to write a program that asks the user for a letter (R,G,B) and then after five output the result. There cannot be 2 letters in a row. I get `indexoutofbounds` when I enter the third letter and the double letter check does not work.

```
package absolutejava;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class RGB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        boolean isColor = false;
        String finalString = "";
        int i = 0;
        int j = 1;

        String temp = "";
        for (count = 0; count < 5;) {
            System.out.println("Enter a color. Use R for red, G for green, and B for blue.");
            temp = kb.nextLine();

            if ((temp.equals("R") || temp.equals("G") || temp.equals("B"))) {
                isColor = true;
                temp += temp;

            } else {
                isColor = false;
                System.out.println("Invald Color, please choose again");
            }

            if (isColor == true && j < 6 && i < 5) {
                count++;
                if (temp.length() > 2 && temp.length() <= 5 && finalString.substring(i, j).equals(temp.substring(i - 1, j - 1))) {
                    System.out.println("Two colors cannot be next to each other ");
                    isColor = false;
                    count--;

                } else if (temp.length() == 5) {
                    finalString = finalString + temp.substring(i);
                    //debugging line
                    System.out.println("i " + i + "j " + j + "count " + count + " " + finalString + " length " + temp.length());
                    i++;
                    j++;
                } else {
                    finalString = finalString + temp.substring(i, j);
                    //debugging line
                    System.out.println("i " + i + "j " + j + "count " + count + " " + finalString + " length " + temp.length());
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(finalString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a variable to keep track of the previous color? If the current color entered is equal to the previous color, ask the user to enter the color again. Else, proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

The following line is definitely wrong:

```
temp += temp;
```

You're replacing `temp` with the current input every iteration, so this will have no effect. Even if that *wasn't* the case, you'd just be adding the same string to itself - e.g. "A" would become "AA."

I assume you meant

```
finalString += temp;
```

or something to that effect.

In general, it seems like you're mixing up `temp` and `final` in a few places.

One more thing: don't explicitly compare to `true` and `false`, it's unnecessary and is generally considered poor style.